# Crysis Very High graphics settings not available

Tags: graphics-card, crysis

I have
Motherboard: Intel DG35EC
Processor: Dual Core 2.0 GHz
RAM: 1 GB
Graphics Card: Forsa nVidia 9800GT 1 GB
Operating System: Windows XP

In graphics settings last option available is "High" for everything. "Very High" option is disabled in Crysis. Why? I don't want all settings to be Very High, i need to set only few. Is there any Ultra High option also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "very high" option is only available on a DirectX 10 capable operating system (Windows Vista/7) with a DirectX 10 capable graphics card. Your graphics card is DX10-capable, but you would need to upgrade to Windows Vista or Windows 7 to use DirectX10-only effects.

There is an inofficial way of enabling most of those effects without using DirectX 10:
[Guide on how to enable "very high" settings on Windows XP](http://www.tweakguides.com/Crysis_13.html).

There is no official ultra-high setting, but there are a number of additional tweaks you can apply, some of those are listed in the guide I linked to. But your 8900GT is probably not powerful enough to run those kinds of settings at high resolution and anti-aliasing.

Comment: I am now playing Crysis at Very High settings using the link above. With 1152x864 and 8x antialiasing i have almost no problem in fps.

Comment: Your resolution is very low in comparison to current monitors, at higher resolutions you'll need a better graphics card.